# rpm progress bar reaches 100% but package is not installed

Tags: centos, rpm

I'm trying to install telnet with rpm (can't use yum) with the following command:

```
rpm -ivh telnet-0.17-48.el6.src-2.rpm

   1:telnet                 warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
...
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
########################################### [100%]
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
```

I assume that the warnings shouldn't prevent me from installing,
and since the progress bar hits 100%, I thought it worked.
But when I query for telnet, I get:

```
package telnet is not installed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you installed a `src.rpm`; not a normal rpm. A source rpm contains the source code and spec file; not the compiled version of the program. You should look for a normal rpm (without the `.src.` in the name).